# how to start animaton from any postion in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my character should move to the right and to the left from any point, but when I click on the animation button, the character teleports back to the starting point, and does not start moving to the right or left from the point where he stayed at the moment the button was pressed
https://youtu.be/clSaW9MRpSM
video

```
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.player{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    

}

.block{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 400px;
    animation: block 1s infinite linear;
}

#game{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes block{
    0%{top: -50;}
    100%{top: 420;}
}


@keyframes gor{
    0%{left: 0px;}
    50%{left: 450px;}
    100%{left: 0px;}

}

@keyframes gol{
    0%{right: 450px;}
    50%{right: 0px;}
    100%{right: 450px;}
}

.animater{
    animation: gor 1s ;
    position: relative;
}

.animatel{
    animation: gol 1s ;
    position: relative ;
}
```

Comment: We really can't debug CSS without the HTML. Please include everything we need in order to help you. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

js code

```
   var player = document.getElementById("player");
    var block = document.getElementById("block");


function goleft(argument){
    player.classList.add("animatel");
    setTimeout(function(){
        player.classList.remove("animatel");
    },1);
    console.log("left");

}

function goright(argument){
    player.classList.add("animater");

    console.log("right");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.